# R: Divide column Y by Z with absolute (positive) output, then sum output per unique value for column X

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation, integer-arithmetic

for every `jobtask` I am trying to divide `value` by `weight` with two separate columns for calculating +1 values and the -1 values. For `outputnegative`, I would specifically need absolute (positive) values.

Having this, I would then like to add 2 more columns again that per value for `occupation` (a/b/c) sums the `outputpositive` and `outputnegative`. I can't seem to figure it out, any help would be much appreciated!!!

```
occupation <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
jobtask <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12")
value <- c("1", "1", "0", "-1", "-1", "0", "-1", "1", "-1", "1", "0", "0")
weight <- c("95", "81", "97", "65", "43", "92", "89", "43", "58", "99", "35", "69")

df <- data.frame(occupation, jobtask, value, weight)
```

Desired output below:

```
   occupation jobtask value weight outputpos outputneg occupationpos occupationneg
1           a       1     1     95      0.95                    1.76          0.65
2           a       2     1     81      0.81                    1.76          0.65
3           a       3     0     97                              1.76          0.65
4           a       4    -1     65               -0.65          1.76          0.65
5           b       5    -1     43               -0.43          0.43          1.22
6           b       6     0     92                              0.43          1.22
7           b       7    -1     89               -0.89          0.43          1.22
8           b       8     1     43      0.43                    0.43          1.22
9           c       9    -1     58               -0.58          0.99          0.58
10          c      10     1     99      0.99                    0.99          0.58
11          c      11     0     35                              0.99          0.58
12          c      12     0     69                              0.99          0.58
```

Extra addition to fix multiple years. In the df every row is one year, so the "sum" for that specific occupation is now 5.42, while it should be 0.95 + 0.81 = 1.76 like it was in the example above. Every `jobtask` has different number of `year`, so cannot simply divide by one number to account for the number of years. Any suggestions?

````
 occupation jobtask year value weight outputpos outputneg occupationpos occupationneg
1          a       1 2015     1     95      0.95                    5.42              
2          a       1 2016     1     95      0.95                    5.42             
3          a       1 2017     1     95      0.95                    5.42             
4          a       1 2018     1     95      0.95                    5.42             
5          a       2 2015     1     81      0.81                    5.42             
6          a       2 2016     1     81      0.81                    5.42             ```
````

Comment: Implemented and works; thank you!! Upvoted as well!

Comment: Okay, so I guess you want the `group_by(year)` instead of `group_by(occupation)` i.e. first row + 5th row for 2015.  I was thinking that you want to group by occupation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could first convert the column types to numeric with `type.convert`, then create a column of 'output' by dividing 'weight' by 100, then with `case_when` create the 'outputpos', 'outputneg' based on the value 1 or -1, grouped by 'occupation', get the `sum` of 'output' where 'value' is 1, and 'value' is -1 to create the 'occupation_pos', 'occupation_neg'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df %>% 
   mutate(output = weight/100, 
          outputpos = case_when(value == 1 ~ output), 
          outputneg = case_when(value == -1 ~ -1 *output)) %>% 
   group_by(occupation) %>% 
   mutate(occupation_pos = sum(output[value == 1]),
          occupation_neg = sum(output[value == -1])) %>%
   select(-output)
# A tibble: 12 x 8
# Groups:   occupation [3]
#   occupation jobtask value weight outputpos outputneg occupation_pos occupation_neg
#   <chr>        <int> <int>  <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 a                1     1     95      0.95    NA               1.76          0.65 
# 2 a                2     1     81      0.81    NA               1.76          0.65 
# 3 a                3     0     97     NA       NA               1.76          0.65 
# 4 a                4    -1     65     NA       -0.65            1.76          0.65 
# 5 b                5    -1     43     NA       -0.43            0.43          1.32 
# 6 b                6     0     92     NA       NA               0.43          1.32 
# 7 b                7    -1     89     NA       -0.89            0.43          1.32 
# 8 b                8     1     43      0.43    NA               0.43          1.32 
# 9 c                9    -1     58     NA       -0.580           0.99          0.580
#10 c               10     1     99      0.99    NA               0.99          0.580
#11 c               11     0     35     NA       NA               0.99          0.580
#12 c               12     0     69     NA       NA               0.99          0.580
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you so much for the answer. I have one problem now, that is I measure for multiple years (long format, e.g. 5 rows for 5 years). So the sum is now the total of all years, though I would need the sum to be divided by the number of years for that specific `task_id`. Namely, `year` values differs from 2 to 5 years per unique task_id. How could I do that?

Comment: @Marc-Marijn where is the 'year' column in the dataset.  Do you need to `group_by(occupation, year) %>%` and then create the occupation_pos, _neg column?

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have edited. Thank you for looking into it!!

Comment: @Marc-Marijn do you need `group_by(occupation, jobtask)` and rest remains the same

Comment: I added the new df in the bottom as an addition, you can see year there. when group_by(occupation, jobtask) it still sums up every single year (while the output is only 1 value per task, does not depend on year)

Comment: @Marc-Marijn can you please edit and add a reproducible example as I am not able to understand the issue from that output alone

Comment: I will e-mail you tomorrow ok? It's 05h30AM here, time to sleep. Thank you!!

Comment: @Marc-Marijn based on the output showed, it is `group_by(year)`